# Whats the alternative to async.forEachOf or upgrade version in Debian Buster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, debian, async.js

Currently, I am running my node application under buster version of debian. It was working fine on my windows machine but when I uploaded to debian machine, its throwing me following error:

```
 {iov_base="<h1>async.forEachOf is not a function</h1>\n<h2></h2>\n<pre>TypeError: async.forEachOf is not a function\n    at /usr/lib/nodejs/test/routes/index.js:541:11\n    at /usr/sha
re/javascript/async/async.js:570:21\n    at /usr/share/javascript/async/async.js:249:17\n    at /usr/share/javascript/async/async.js:125:13\n    at Array.forEach (&lt;anonymous&gt;)\n    at _each (/usr/share/javascript/async/async.js:46:
24)\n    at async.each (/usr/share/javascript/async/async.js:124:9)\n    at _asyncMap (/usr/share/javascript/async/async.js:248:13)\n    at Object.map (/usr/share/javascript/async/async.js:219:23)\n    at _parallel (/usr/share/javascript
/async/async.js:568:20)</pre>\n", iov_len=683}], 2) = 885
```

Here is my code:
/usr/lib/nodejs/test/routes/index.js

```
   534 router.post("/Add/",function(req,res){ 
    535         console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.domains)); 
    536         var EmptyArr1 = []; 
    537         var EmptyArr2 = []; 
    538         async.parallel([ 
    539                 function (callback) { 
    540                         if(req.body.webhostinglength > 0){ 
    541                                 async.forEachOf(req.body.webhosting, function (value, key, callback1) { 
    542                                         var webhosting = value; 
    543                                         var i = key; 
    544                                         var domain = req.body.domains[key];
```

Here is the async version in debian:
node-async:
Installed: 0.8.0-3
Candidate: 0.8.0-3
Version table:
*** 0.8.0-3 500
500 http://packages.hostway.net/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

I am afraid above version is the latest version in debian? Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What all exactly are you doing inside the callback there? If it were me, it'd probably be a lot easier to use standard `async`/`await`, which are supported on every reasonably modern version of Node

Comment: Dont install node from apt, install it using nvm.

Comment: Do you have to use the Debian package? Can you instead install the async package using npm?